# Prolog beginner. How to take list as parameter and pass it on

Tags: prolog

I am a total beginner at Prolog. I am struggling with creating a rule, which takes a list as parameter and passes the list onto another rule. Here is my code:

```
combine([], '').
combine([L|List], Total) :-
    combine(List, CombinedRest),
    atom_concat(L, CombinedRest, Total).

findHeadline([W|Words], Combined) :- 
    combine(Words, Combined).

findHeadline2([Words], Combined) :- 
    combine(Words, Combined).
```

findHeadline works as expected, but findHeadline2 does not. Here is the output:

```
1 ?- findHeadline([billig, enkeltmand], Combination).
Combination = enkeltmand.

2 ?- findHeadline2([billig, enkeltmand], Combination).
false.
```

The output I was expecting from findHeadline was:

```
Combination = billigenkeltmand.
```

How can it be that this does not work?

I tried to utilize trace in SWI-prolog, but it gave me no clue whatsoever, as the findHeadline rule just exits immediately and does not call the combine rule at all.

Comment: Since `Words` is already a list then `[Words]` is a list consisting of one element. You just want `findHeadLine2(Words, Combined)`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not very clear what it is exactly that you are after. If you just want to concatenate a list of atoms to get one atom, use [`atomic_list_concat/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=atomic_list_concat/2) available in SWI-Prolog:

```
?- atomic_list_concat([foo, bar, baz], C).
C = foobarbaz.
```

At the moment, your `findHeadline2/2` reads:

"Take a list containing exactly one element, and `combine/2` that element."

This is not what you are after, I have the feeling.

Your `findHeadline/2`, on the other hand, says:

"Take a list of at least one element, and `combine/2` all elements except the first".

**This is important**: never ever ignore compilation warnings. You get code that does something, but you can be almost certain that it does not do what you want it to do, which is bad, or that if someone else reads your code, they will be confused, which is also bad.

Comment: You solved it. I am embarrassed to have asked this question. The solution was to remove the [] around Words: 
findHeadline2(Words, Combined) :- 
    combine(Words, Combined).
You are right that this program did not make much sense, I just condensed a lot of code to narrow down the problem to the smallest piece of code that did not work. Thank you very very much for your help!

Comment: @David everyone has to start somewhere, and unlike most questions on this site, yours showed actual effort :) BTW: you should consider using `names_like_this`, instead of `namesInCamelCase`. It is just how most Prolog code is written, it does not make your program any better or worse.

Comment: `using_underscores_is_significantly_more_readable`, `asYouCanReadilyVerifyforYourselvesOnLongerNames!`.

Comment: @mat Thank you guys for your help. Underscores it is from now on. I have also started using atomic_list_concat. A positive effect of Prolog is also better sleep, as my brain gets exhausted from thinking in new ways.